# Taylor Series Expansion of $\tanh x$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

I know how to find the Taylor expansion of both $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$, but how would you find the Taylor expansion of $\tanh x$. It seems you can't just divide both the Taylor series of $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$ so how would you do it?

Any suggestions? I saw it contains the Bernoulli series, what is that exactly?

Kind Regards

Comment: You could do using long division. Otherwise, as usual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may too use the method I used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286529/how-to-expand-tan-x-in-taylor-order-to-ox6/286628#286628) for the expansion of $\tan$ :

Integrate repetitively $\ \tanh'(x)=1-\tanh(x)^2\ $ starting with $\,\tanh(x)\approx x$ :

\begin{align}
\tanh(x)&\small{=}\ x+O\bigl(x^2\bigr)\\
&\small{=\int 1-\left(x+O\bigl(x^2\bigr)\right)^2\,dx}=x-\frac {x^3}3+O\bigl(x^4\bigr)\\
&\small{=\int 1-\left(x-\frac {x^3}3+O\bigl(x^4\bigr)\right)^2dx=\int 1-x^2+\frac {2x^4}3\,dx-O\bigl(x^6\bigr)}=x-\frac {x^3}3+\frac {2x^5}{15}-O\bigl(x^6\bigr)\\
&= \cdots\\
\end{align}

Every integration gives another coefficient of $\ \displaystyle\tanh(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n\ (-1)^n\,x^{2n+1}\ $ and we get simply :
$$a_0=1,\; a_{n+1}=\frac 1{2n+3} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\ a_{n-k},\ \text{for}\;n>0$$
i.e. the [sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Taylor_series_of_tan_and_tanh) (with alternating signs for $\tanh$) : $$(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left(\frac 11,\frac 13, \frac 2{15}, \frac {17}{315}, \frac {62}{2835}, \frac{1382}{155925},\cdots\right)$$

We may probably deduce the [recurrence relation of Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition) in function of this one (or vice et versa) but I didn't try that yet.

Comment: What does $O$ stand for?

Comment: @TheLastCipher: See ["Big O notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). For example $\;f(x)=O\left(x^2\right)\;$ means that there exist $M$ and $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\;|f(x)| \le \; M x^2\;$ for $x\ge x_0$ (it is not really important here and this answer would probably be clearer without it!).

Comment: Can I suppose for any function $f(x)$ approximately $x$?

Comment: Sorry @JoãoVíctorMelo but your question is unclear... My point was that you could start with $\,\tanh(x)\approx x$, continue with $\,\tanh(x)\approx \int 1-x^2\,dx\,$ and so on...

Answer (score 6):

\begin{eqnarray}
\tanh x &=& x - \frac {x^3} {3} + \frac {2x^5} {15} - \frac {17x^7} {315} + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n} x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}, \left |x \right | < \frac {\pi} {2} \\
\end{eqnarray}
Where $B_{m}$ is the $m$-th Bernoulli number defined as
\begin{equation}
B_m(n) = \sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{v=0}^k(-1)^v\binom kv\frac{\left( n+v\right) ^m}{k+1}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes but where does the Bernoulli number come from, why is it here?

Comment: See next comment

Comment: (+1) Can you explain the derivation of the formula? :)

Comment: There is a typo: $B_m(n)$ should be just $B_m$, right?

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to compute the coefficients of the Taylor series of $\tanh$ is to consider that:
$$\cosh(z)=\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right)$$
hence:
$$ \log\cosh z = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right)$$
and by differentiating:
$$ \tanh z = 2z\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{4}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}}{1+\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}}$$
so:
$$ [z^{2k+1}]\tanh z = 2\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi^{2k+2}}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1/2)^{2k+2}}=2\frac{(-2)^k}{\pi^{2k+2}}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2k+2}}$$
giving:

> $$ [z^{2k+1}]\tanh z = 2\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi^{2k+2}}\left(1-\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}\right)\zeta(2k+2).$$

Comment: (+1) Nice solution but I cannot follow each step as it seems some parts are summarized. Where the first identity come from? Also, what does the bracket $[]$ mean here (4th equation)? and also how the function $\zeta$ appeared?

Comment: @H.R.: the first identity is Weierstrass product, $[z^k]\,f(z)$ stands for the coefficient of $z^k$ in the Laurent series of $f(z)$ around the origin and $\zeta$ comes from $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2k+2}}$.

Comment: I think that would be nice to mention these in the answer. :) Would you please take look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2314924/computing-the-integral-int-tanhbx-a-cos-beta-x-dx) which indeed lead me here.

Comment: You are an excellent mathematician, but by reworking the calculations here, I saw that you omitted many passages.

Comment: In your last formula is factor `2^(2k+2)` missing, correct is (in Mathematica notation) `Table[2^(2 k + 3)*(-1)^k/Pi^(2 k + 2)*(1 - 1/4^(k + 1)) * Zeta[2 k + 2], {k, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Can you explain better the [] in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a universal theory of all places where Bernoulli numbers arise, but Euler-Maclaurin summation explains many of their more down-to-earth occurrences.

The heuristic explanation (due to Lagrange) is as follows.  The first difference operator defined by $\Delta f(n) = f(n+1)-f(n)$ and summation are inverses, in the same sense in which differentiation and integration are inverses.  This just amounts to a telescoping series: $\sum_{a \le i < b} \Delta f(i) = f(b) - f(a)$.

Now by Taylor's theorem, $f(n+1) = \sum_{k \ge 0} f^{(k)}(n)/k!$ (under suitable hypotheses, of course).  If we let $D$ denote the differentation operator defined by $Df = f'$, and $S$ denote the shift operator defined by $Sf(n) = f(n+1)$, then Taylor's theorem tells us that $S = e^D$.  Thus, because $\Delta = S-1$, we have $\Delta = e^D - 1$.

Now summing amounts to inverting $\Delta$, or equivalently applying $(e^D-1)^{-1}$.  If we expand this in terms of powers of $D$, the coefficients are Bernoulli numbers (divided by factorials).  Because of the singularity at "$D=0$", the initial term involves antidifferentiation $D^{-1}$, i.e., integration.  Thus, we have expanded a sum as an integral plus correction terms involving higher derivatives, with Bernoulli number coefficients.

Specifically,
$$
\sum_{a \le i < b} f(i) = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx + \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{B_k}{k!} (f^{(k-1)}(b) - f^{(k-1)}(a)).
$$
(Subtracting the values at $b$ and $a$ just amounts to the analogue of turning an indefinite integral into a definite integral.)

Comment: Hi I am a high school student in 12th grade, I probably should have mentioned this, is there anyway you could simplify your explanation, for example I am unsure what a difference operator is, do you mind explaining?