# Maclaurin polynomial of tan(x)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The method used to find the Maclaurin polynomial of sin(x), cos(x), and $e^x$ requires finding several derivatives of the function. However, you can only take a couple derivatives of tan(x) before it becomes unbearable to calculate.

Is there a relatively easy way to find the Maclaurin polynomial of tan(x)?

I considered using tan(x)=sin(x)/cos(x) somehow, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: A recurrence formula for the coefficients was obtained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/286628/21783).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long division of series.

$$ \matrix{ & x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2 x^5}{15} + \dots
\cr 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \ldots & ) \overline{x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} + \dots}\cr
& x - \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^5}{24} + \dots\cr & --------\cr
& 
\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{30} + \dots\cr
& \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^5}{6} + \dots\cr
& ------\cr
&\frac{2 x^5}{15} + \dots \cr
&\frac{2 x^5}{15} + \dots \cr
& ----}$$

Answer (score 3):

Starting with $y=\tan x$ you can generate successive derivatives quite easily by getting rid of terms involving $x$ as follows:

$$y'=\sec^2 x=1+y^2$$
$$\Rightarrow y''=2yy'$$
$$\Rightarrow y'''=2(y')^2+2yy''$$
$$\Rightarrow y^{(4)}=4y'y''+2y'y''+2yy'''=6y'y''+2yy'''$$

And so on...

Answer (score 3):

Tangent's derivatives are not cyclic. If you differentiate $e^x$, $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$ and even $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ enough times, you'll eventually end up with the original function providing a nice formula for the Taylor coefficients. A way to state this periodicity is to say that they all satisfy a differential equation of the form $y^{(n)}=y$ for some $n$. This property means that their Taylor Series will have some kind of periodic relation among the coefficients.

Not so with tangent.

Instead, tangent satisfies the differential equation $y'=1+y^2$. This is because $\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = \sec^2(x) = 1+\tan^2(x)$, via the Pythagorean Theorem. This can  be used to compute specific values for the coefficients. But the general form of the Taylor Expansion is

$$
\tan(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}}{2n(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}
$$

where the $B_n$ are the [Bernoulli Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html), which are defined to be the Taylor Series coefficients of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$. I'll let [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Taylor_Series_Expansion_for_Tangent_Function) provide the proof of this formula.

Comment: It seems like the ProofWiki proof is not there anymore...
While I'm struggling to find a proof for this

Comment: ok, a nice proof is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098941/bernoulli-numbers-taylor-series-expansion-of-tan-x

Answer (score 1):

> $\tan x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_{2n+1}\cdot\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}~,~$ where $A_{2n+1}$ are the so-called [“zag-”](http://oeis.org/A000182) or [tangent numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation#Related_integer_sequences).

They go hand-in-hand with their complementary counterparts  $A_{2n}$ , commonly called [“zig-”](http://oeis.org/A000364)

or *secant numbers* : $~\sec x=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_{2n}\cdot\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}~.~$ The entire sequence $A_n$ is called [“zigzag-”](http://oeis.org/A000111) or

*up/down numbers*. As can be glanced from the various links, no “nice” formula or algorithm

exists for determining them.