# Bernoulli number for the Maclaurin series of $tan(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that the series representation of $\tan(x)$ is:

$x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}...$

I can derive this by using the fact that $\tan(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$. But I don't know how to find the general sigma formula for this function.

I have seen the general formula here:
[Maclaurin polynomial of tan(x)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546539/maclaurin-polynomial-of-tanx/1546566#1546566)

But I don't know how the Bernoulli number is involved. Can you explain this further so I can understand?

Comment: cf. the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098941/bernoulli-numbers-taylor-series-expansion-of-tan-x)

Comment: The answer is not there, the link to ProofWiki is invalid

Comment: Here is the real answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098941/bernoulli-numbers-taylor-series-expansion-of-tan-x