# How do you find the Maclaurin polynomial for tangent?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

$$f(x) = 3 + \int\limits_0^{2x} \tan t ~\mathrm{d} t$$

Like I already know how to find arctan in sigma notation, but how do I find the maclaurin series for tangent?

Comment: Do you mean a formula for the general term or how to find its expansion at a given order?

Comment: how to find at a given order

Comment: Perform the division by *increasing* powers of the expansion of $\sin x$ by the expansion of $\cos x$ up to this order.

Comment: See  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/286540/362009

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$\int \tan(t) dt
=\int \dfrac{\sin(t)dt}{\cos(t)}
=\int \dfrac{(-\cos'(t))dt}{\cos(t)}
$

Look familiar?